# Hidg1 hidg0 nethunter kernel

Tags: kernel, kali-linux

Проблема в том что я собрал ядро под nethunter на 9 android. Пропатчил и интернет драйвера и usb-gadget драйвера ядро запокавал в zip файл с помощью anykernel3 установил на телефон без ошибок, установил magisk, потом Nethunter пытаюсь произвести аттаку badusb запускаю, ничего не происходит решил зайти в папку dev в корневом каталоге, зашёл, а там нет hidg1, только какие-то файлы at_usb0, at_usb1, at_usb. Самое интересное, что файл hidg0 есть. В интернете советуют пропатчить usb-gadget который я уже патчил. В общем помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: С чем **конкретно** помочь?

Comment: Помочь понять как исправить то что у меня нет hidg1